# KeyError when plotting pandas dataframe with matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I use weather data csv and when i plot wind it show keyword error

Here is my data:

```
    Year    Month   Day Hour    Temperature Wind
0   2019    3   18  0   22.02   7.42
1   2019    3   18  1   21.48   6.88
2   2019    3   18  2   21.09   6.84
3   2019    3   18  3   20.75   7.20
4   2019    3   18  4   20.43   7.56
```

Now when i attempt to plot

```
import matplotlib  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
import numpy as np  
plt.plot( data['Wind'])
plt.title('Wind Speed')

plt.ylim(0.0, 10.5 )
plt.ylim(0.0, 20.09)
plt.show()
```

It show this error

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/envs/tesnorenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2655             try:
-> 2656                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2657             except KeyError:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'Wind'


pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'Wind'
```

When i use Day, Month and hour it plot right but it not working in Temperature and Wind

It work fine. Please help me i can't find error

Comment: what is the output of `print(data.columns.values)` ?

Comment: it show  correct ['Year' 'Month' 'Day' 'Hour' 'Temperature  ' 'Wind ']

Comment: You have a space in your column name: `'Wind '` You can either call `plt.plot( data['Wind '])` with the trailing space or clean your columns : `data.columns = data.columns.str.strip()`

Comment: Yes, it is space in Wind and Temperature. I removed it now it working... Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your columns have spaces:

```
['Year' 'Month' 'Day' 'Hour' 'Temperature ' 'Wind ']
```

You can see that `'Temperature '` and `'Wind '` have trailing spaces.

Whenever you see a `KeyError` then you should look at what your columns really are, not what they look like by doing `print(data.columns.tolist())`

So you can either call the column correctly:

```
plt.plot( data['Wind '])
```

or clean up the columns:

```
data.columns = data.columns.str.strip()
```

to remove leading and trailing spaces